# Navigation issue after broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, flags, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working in a feature to catch a call when is finished, I am using a `BroadcastReceiver`, when the Call is finished I need to redirect the user to a `MenuActivity` or `FeedbackActivity` (It depends of the user settings) I am using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

try {
   if (defaultFeedback) {
      Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Go to Feedback 1 after Call");
      intent.setClass(context, FeedbackActivity.class);
   } else {
      intent.setClass(context, MenuActivity.class);
      Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Go to MenuActivity after Call");
   }

   context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Print Exception
}
```

The respective Activity is open, the problem is When I change the Activity and minimize the current Activity, when I resume the activity again doesn't appear the last one, the App load the previous (activity that was executed since Broadcast). i.g Since Broadcast open `FeedbackActivity` -> Fill the info and Touch in Next Button -> `MenuActivity` is now presented -> Minimize App (Touch Home Button) -> Resume the App from the Recent Apps List and the view that is shown is `FeedbackActivity` again instead `MenuActivity`.

The Intent that I am using for changing sin FeedbackActivity to MenuActivity is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FeedbackActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

I was making test, and when the App is resumed the Intent is always the same that was execute for the Broadcast, I added a bool extra for change it value in `MenuActivity` to true (I left false in `Broadcast`), but when App is resumed again the Put extra is false again.

I really hope that you someone can help me.

Comment: Why you do not startActivity(intent) instend of intent.setClass(context, FeedbackActivity.class); ???

Comment: @SahdevRajput74, I am going to try and I'll tell you

Comment: okay try it may be work for you

Comment: @SahdevRajput74, did not work